# Well Define Of Inequality of Real Number

Tags: inequality, definition, real-numbers

**Definition**

For two sequences $\alpha,\beta : \Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb Q$

Define $\alpha \sim \beta$ when one can pick $N$ s.t. $\forall i \ge N$, $\lvert \alpha(i)-\beta(i)\rvert \lt e$

Since $\sim$ is equivalence relation of the set $\Bbb F = \{\alpha: \Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb Q$}, call the element of Quotient set $\Bbb R = \Bbb F/\sim$ real number.when

Now

Define $[\alpha], [\beta] \in \Bbb R$, if there $\exists d>0 \in \Bbb Q $ and $ N \in \Bbb N$ s.t. $\forall i \ge N$, $\lvert \alpha(i)-\beta(i)\rvert \lt d$ , $[\alpha]\gt [\beta]$.

**Question**

From above, I have been requested to check whether the inequality of $[\alpha], [\beta]$ is well-defined.

Well-defined is still ambiguous term to me.

What do I have to check?

Comment: $\sim$ as you have defined it is not an equivalence relation. You need to be able to pick this $N$ for each $e$ (more precisely, for each positive rational $e$ or for every $e=1/n$ for some natural $n$, or something of the sort).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[\alpha]$ denotes the equivalence class that includes $\alpha$. However, there are other ways we could have represented this equivalence class. For example, if $\beta \sim \alpha$, we could have istead written it as $[\beta]$. Thus, whenever we define a relation between two equivalence classes $[\alpha]$ and $[\beta]$ where the definition depends explicitly on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (as does your definition for inequality), we face a potential problem: what if the relation may or may not hold, depending on how we choose to represent the equivalence classes? If this happens, then the relation is not well-defined.

For example, if I attempted to define a function $F: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{Q}$ given by $F([\alpha]) = \alpha(1)$, this would not be a well defined function for the above reason.

So, when the problem asks you to prove that $<$ is well defined, it wants you to prove the following: If $\alpha \sim \alpha'$ and $\beta \sim \beta '$ and $[\alpha]<[\beta]$, show that $[\alpha'] < [\beta']$.

EDIT- To show that inequality is well defined, suppose $\alpha \sim \alpha'$, $\beta \sim \beta'$, and that $[\alpha] < [\beta]$. Then there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ and $d\in \mathbb{Q}^{> 0}$ such that whenever $n>N$ we have $\beta(n) - \alpha(n) > d$.

Since $\alpha' \sim \alpha$ and $\beta' \sim \beta$, there exists $N'\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N'> N$ and such that whenever $n>N'$ we have $\vert \alpha(n)-\alpha'(n)\vert < d/4$ and $\vert\beta(n)-\beta'(n)\vert < d/4$. Then
$$\beta'(n) - \alpha'(n) = (\beta'(n) - \beta(n))+(\beta(n)-\alpha(n))+(\alpha(n) -
 \alpha'(n))$$
$$\geq -d/4 + d - d/4 = d/2$$
So we have that $\beta'(n) > \alpha'(n)$, and that $\vert \beta'(n)-\alpha'(n)\vert > d/2$, and so $[\alpha'] < [\beta]'$.

$\;$

Comment: why does the function $F: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb Q$ given by $F([\alpha]) = \alpha(1)$ is not well-defined? Regarding your explanation, this defniton depend on how we choose to represent the equivalence class - but can't explicitly understand the reason with counterexample

Comment: Let's say we tried to figure out what $F(0)$ is. Recall that $0$ (the real number) is the equivalence class of all Cauchy sequences of rational numbers which converge to $0$ (the rational number). Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be sequences such that for all $i$ we have $\alpha(i) = 1/i$ and $\beta(i)=0$. Then $0=[\alpha]=[\beta]$. However, according to my definition for $F$, we have $F(0)=F([\alpha])=1$, but also that $F(0) = F([\beta])=0$, a contradiction. Thus, my definition doesn't give us a valid function.

Comment: understood. So that's the reason why we intentionally take the same but different in notation and check whether still the definition works. Will add the answer soon

Comment: please check whether my answer is okay

Comment: In general, you can't subtract inequalities from each other as you did. This is to say, if $a<b$ and $c<d$, it may not be the case that $a-c<b-d$. Further, in the definition of inequality, shouldn't it say $\vert \alpha((i)-\beta(i) \vert > d$? The idea is that, past a certain point, $\alpha$ should always be greater than $\beta$, but the two shouldn't become arbitrarily close. I'll sketch a proof for this problem in my current answer.

Comment: is there any chance at the last inequality, $\beta'(n)-\beta(n)$ be $\lt {-d \over 4}$ such as $-d$ which makes its absolute value bigger than ${d \over 4}$?

Comment: No. By hypothesis, $\vert \beta'(n) - \beta(n) \vert < d/4$, which implies that $-d/4 < \beta'(n)-\beta(n) < d/4$.

Comment: edited the direction of inequality of d/4 of each alpha and beta

Answer (score 1):

$\forall \alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R$ take $\alpha',\beta'$ s.t. $\alpha'\sim\alpha,\; \beta' \sim \beta$ and

Suppose $[\alpha] \gt [\beta]$ Then

$\exists d>0 \in \Bbb Q $ and $ N \in \Bbb N$

s.t. $\forall i \ge N$, $\lvert \alpha(i)-\beta(i)\rvert \lt d$

one can take $N_1, N_2$ s.t. $\forall i \ge N_1$, $\lvert \alpha(i)-\alpha'(i)\rvert \lt e$ and $\forall i \ge N_2$, $\lvert \beta(i)-\beta(i)'\rvert \lt e$

since $\alpha'\sim\alpha,\; \beta' \sim \beta$

Now let $N_{sup} = sup\{N_1, N_2\}$ then

$\exists d>0 \in \Bbb Q $ and $ N_{sup} \in \Bbb N$

s.t. $\forall i \ge N_{sup}$, $\lvert \alpha'(i)-\beta'(i)\rvert \lt d$

since for $N_{sup}$,

$\lvert \alpha(i)\rvert-\lvert\alpha'(i)\rvert \le\lvert \alpha(i)-\alpha'(i)\rvert \lt e$ (1)

$\lvert \beta(i)\rvert-\lvert\beta(i)'\rvert \le \lvert \beta(i)-\beta'(i)\rvert \lt e$ (2)

$\lvert \alpha(i)\rvert-\lvert\beta(i)\rvert \le \lvert \alpha(i)-\beta(i)\rvert \lt d$ (3)

(2)-(1)+(3)  derives  $\lvert \alpha'(i)\rvert-\lvert\beta'(i)\rvert \le\lvert \alpha'(i)-\beta'(i)\rvert \lt d$